# Hibernate and spring mvc Deleting and updating

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

We are developing a spring application with Spring MVC and hibernate. Now we ran into a problem that we can't solve.. The problem arises when we try to delete something.

If we delete the page just loads fine and goes further like everything is succeeded, but the value in the database isn't deleted.

Here is our code:

**This is the TestDao**

```
@Repository
public class TestDaoImpl implements TestDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public Test get(int id) {
        return (Test)this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Test WHERE id =:ident").setParameter("ident",id).uniqueResult();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {

        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(this.get(id));

    }
}
```

**This is our service (business layer)**

```
@Service("testService")
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    private final TestDao testDao;

    @Inject
    public TestServiceImpl(TestDao testDao)
    {
        this.testDao = testDao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(int id) {
          testDao.delete(id);
    }
}
```

**And this is the controller:**

```
@Controller
public class TestingController {

    @Qualifier("testService")
    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/testing")
    public ModelAndView testing()
    {
        testService.delete(1);
        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }

}
```

**This is the hibernate configuration:**

```
<!-- Parse database properties -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/db.properties"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>db/mappings/User.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/Authority.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/Car.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/Address.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/DrivingDay.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/Message.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/Ride.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/RouteAgreement.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/Route.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/RouteTime.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/SocialMediaLogin.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/Variables.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/Waypoint.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>db/mappings/Test.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
               <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

I know it's a wall of code, I'm sorry about that, but I thought I provide as many details as possible.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** There is a value with id 1 in the database.

Comment: Have you called flush? May be this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235868/hibernate-is-not-deleting-my-objects-why

Comment: @thinksteep we can call flush() but it closes the session and that's something we don't want, because sometimes we need to do a couple of transactions.

Comment: I know why your test is not working, Since spring tests are designed not to commit transaction, You can do @Rollback(false) on the delete method in TestServiceImpl that should do it, As far the web page did u enable query logging and checked if the query looks right including bind parameters

Comment: @PrasannaTalakanti I'm not running a unit test. I'm testing it in the webbrowser by surfing to it. The only query I get is this:  Hibernate: select test0_.testId as testId14_, test0_.testNaam as testNaam14_, test0_.testGetal as testGetal14_ from test test0_ where test0_.testId=?

Comment: It means only your get query is being executed and delete is never being executed not sure why, Can you run your test first and see it works with RollBack false and entity gets deleted

Comment: @PrasannaTalakanti when I run a test with the rollback (false), it works perfectly..

Comment: That's good It means we can eliminate Spring config as an issue. Is the controller code exactly same as what you posted in your test. Do you have one spring context or one mvc context and one service level ctx?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7757/discussion-between-vince-v-and-prasanna-talakanti)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be missing `tx:annotation-driven` in your xml - this is the one which triggers creation of proxies for @Transaction annotated beans - if the request is not within a transaction the delete will not work.

Comment: It did work, I needed to declare the annotation-driven into servlet-context.xml and not in the root context!! (you need to load it per request) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try,
enclosing your transcation like begin/end like this.

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
// your operation.
tx.commit();
```

Looks like the operation is rolled back after the code execution. you need to commit the transaction.